# How to reload navigationController view while keeping back button?

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on a notes app, and I would like the ability to close and reopen the already open NewNoteViewController(initially called by a RootViewController in a UINavigationView) by pushing a button on the view. Through the help of user **[Sh_Khan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5820010/sh-khan)** in a previous question I was able to reload the NewNoteViewController. Below is the code I use:

```
let currentView  = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "newNote")

self.navigationController?.setViewControllers([currentView ], animated: true)
```

However, when the view reloads the back button to return to the RootViewController is gone. Is there a way to do this while also mainting the back button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should retrieve the current backstack of the navigation controller, drop the last controller from it, append the newly instantiated controller  and set this new array as the view controllers of the navigation controller.

```
if let currentView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "newNote"),
    let vcsWithoutLast = self.navigationController?.viewControllers.dropLast() {
    let newVcs = Array(vcsWithoutLast) + [currentView]
    self.navigationController?.setViewControllers(newVcs, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: I added this code in the New Button function and it worked like a charm. Thanks!

The only thing I changed was line 3. I switched 'Array(vcs)' to 'Array(vcsWithoutLast)'